# Configuring & debugging a new mapnik / tirex installation

Tags: mapnik

I've a stack OpenLayers > Apache mod_tile > tirex working with the tirex test backend on a Ubuntu 10.04 virtual machine.

However, I now have troubles with the mapnik-example backend included with tirex. OpenLayers works fine, mod_tile does not complain about the newly added "AddTileConfig  /tiles/example/ example" to my Apache httpd.conf. Also, the tirex-master receives a request from mod_tile.

I suspect this problem to lie with the configuration of the tirex Mapnik rendering backend. Using tirex-status command I can see tirex-master currently rendering the tiles for the example map. The rendering process times out after about 300 seconds and no (meta)tiles are being written to the tile directory.

I suspect a wrong configuration or problems with user/write access.

Does anyone know where I can find debug information from tirex or mapnik that can help me solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

---

EDIT:
I am looking for clues about what is going on in some logfiles. I suspect the problem to lie with the tirex-backend-mapnik process, which seems to be managed by the tirex-backend-manager process.

In the [OSM Tirex Logging wiki page][1] it says that the tirex-master and tirex-backend-manager will log to the syslog by default, which should be located under /var/log/messages.

This logfile has the following entry at the end

`Dec 23 12:50:13 ubuntumapserver kernel: [10967.139797] mapnik[2079]: segfault at 0 ip 000000000041314b sp 00007fffacfa9530 error 4 in mapnik[400000+1f000]

Dec 23 12:50:14 ubuntumapserver kernel: [10968.391401] mapnik[2077]: segfault at 0 ip 000000000041314b sp 00007fffe23608a0 error 4 in mapnik[400000+1f000]`

Does anyone know have any clues about what can be causing this error?

---

EDIT 2:

Hi Dane,

Thanks for your reply. I installed Mapnik from source using the [Mapnik wiki tutorial][2] (Installation on a VM guest running Ubuntu 10.04 Server x64)

`python scons/scons.py configure DEBUG=True INPUT_PLUGINS=all OPTIMIZATION=3 SYSTEM_FONTS=/usr/share/fonts/
python scons/scons.py
sudo python scons/scons.py install`

I have successfully used Mapnik standalone via the Python commmand line to render images.

Furthermore I did an strace during a request from OpenLayers. (I saw you recommending this elsewhere). I can see mod_tile.so being called. However, there is no data about tirex or mapnik.

[strace][3] 
[config.log from Mapnik installation][4]

Therefore, I guess you might be correct about tirex **not working with a compiled version of Mapnik**. I will try to find out if this is indeed the problem.

1_http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tirex/Logging (About Tirex Logging)
2_http://trac.mapnik.org/wiki/UbuntuInstallationOld (Mapnik installation)
3_http://pastebin.com/L8VBzvgM (strace of a tile request)
4_http://pastebin.com/yvLQDr39 (Mapnik scons config.log)

Comment: That error is not enough provide much of a lead.

I would recommend confirming that Mapnik itself is working properly (I do this by running TileLite: https://bitbucket.org/springmeyer/tilelite/)

How did you install Mapnik? I've heard that tirex may only work with apt-get installed mapnik packages.